# How Is Message Recovery Done in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, actor

In the Erlang/Elixir Actor Model, if an actor sends a message but, for any reason (e.g. network failure, VM crash), it fails to reach the target actor, is there a way to replay that message or does the actor system regard that message as having been sent? Are messages guaranteed to be sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delivery is not guaranteed, but order of delivery is.
See http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2017-September/093564.html

See also the FAQ:
http://erlang.org/faq/academic.html#idp33047120

Comment: section 10.9 in FAQ answered my question